# multimap iterator not working

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

I have a `Playlist` class that has a vector with `Tracks` and each `Track` has a `multimap<long, Note>` as datamember.

```
class Track {
private:
    multimap<long, Note> noteList;
}
```

Using an iterator to acces the tracks is no problem, so this part here is working fine:

```
vector<Track>::iterator trackIT;
    try{
        for(noteIT = trackIT->getNoteList().begin(); noteIT != trackIT->getNoteList().end(); noteIT++){
            cout << "---" << noteIT->second.getName() << endl;
        }
    }catch (int e){
        cout << "exception #" << e << endl;
    }
```

What I want to do next is iterate the `Notes` of each `Track`. But starting from this part all output is stopped. So I only get to see the first tracks name. Any cout's after that are not shown and the compiler isn't giving me any errors. Even the cout inside the try catch block isn't working..

```
vector<Track>::iterator trackIT;
multimap<long, Note>::iterator noteIT;
for(trackIT = this->playlist.getTracklist().begin(); trackIT < this->playlist.getTracklist().end(); trackIT++){
    cout << trackIT->getTrackName() << endl;

    for(noteIT = trackIT->getNoteList().begin(); noteIT != trackIT->getNoteList().end(); noteIT++){
        cout << "---" << noteIT->second.getName() << endl;
    }
}
cout << "random cout that is NOT shown" << endl; // this part doesn't show up in console either
```

Also, the method in my Track class that I'm using to add the Note objects looks like this:

```
void Track::addNote(Note &note) {
    long key = 1000009;
    this->noteList.insert(make_pair(key, note));
}

// I'm adding the notes to the track like this:
Note note1(440, 100, 8, 1, 1);
note1.setName("note1");
synthTrack.addNote(note1);
```

Any ideas why the iterator won't work?

Comment: Something might be wrong with `Note`'s copy constructor. — Shouldn't the type signature be `void Track::addNote(const Note &note)`? Or `void Track::addNote(Note &&note)`.

Comment: What is the value of `this->curMsr`?

Comment: Did you check if `notesIT` is actually at `trackIT->end()`? And what's the value of `this->curMsr`?

Comment: When you call addNote you use 1000009 as key. When you are duing search, you are using multiples of 1000000. It is unlikely to get key 1000009 from it and thus you are getting trackIT->end() all the time. trackIT->end() is not in your container and contains undefined data.

Comment: this->curMsr is 1, so the iterator should point to the first Note

Comment: Strip your code down to an absolute minimal running example which shows the problem, not more than 20 lines should do it.

Comment: The problem was with my multimap-getter returning a copy of the datamember. I don't know why but making the datamember public fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the definitions of `getTrackList` or `getNoteList`, but there's a common mistake people make - if you return a copy of the container instead of a reference to it, the iterators will be pointing to different containers making comparisons impossible. Not only that but since the containers are temporary any use of the iterators results in undefined behavior.

Comment: That was actually the problem. I made the my trackList public and that solved it..

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
noteIT < trackIT->getNoteList().end()
```

To

```
noteIT != trackIT->getNoteList().end()
```

Not all iterators support less than / greater than comparisons.

If you have c++11 you can use a range-based for loop:

```
for (Note& note : trackIT->getNoteList())
```

Or you can use BOOST_FOREACH

```
BOOST_FOREACH (Note& note, trackIT->getNoteList())
```

Comment: This removed the error I was getting, but the `cout` still is not showing. Output stops after the first track name..

Comment: This is for an iOS app. I don't think I can use C++11

Comment: If you are having a new problem with std::cout, I'd say this counts as a different question, do we really want this question to turn into a "How do I fix all the compile errors in my sample program"?

Also without seeing the whole program there's no way to really diagnose the problem. Are your loops nested? I can't tell...

Comment: Yes my loops are nested. I actually asked about the cout first, before mentioning any compiler error. I think the problem is at `noteIT = trackIT->getNoteList().begin();`

Comment: If you want anyone to be able to diagnose this in a sane way you need to post a snippet that contains the nested loops along with the call to std::out that you claim is not executing.

Comment: Hey, I updated my post. The confusing part is that it's not even showing me any errors

Comment: Are you saying that NOTHING shows up? Perhaps your generating an exception. The "compiler" wont show you runtime errors, all it does is compile your code. You could wrap your code with a try/catch block and then in your catch code, write to cout. You might also try writing to std::cerr, perhaps your environment is buffering the output and your program is crashing before it can be flushed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't think of using a try catch block. I tried it now but even the cout in the catch block isn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really hardcoding the track key, then there will only ever be one track in the map because std::map stores unique keys...

```
long key = 1000009; //If yo are really doing this, this key is already inserted so it will fail to insert more.
```

Also, if you would like a more elegant approach you could use function object.

```
struct print_track
{
    void operator()(const Track& track)
    {
        cout << track.getTrackName() << endl;
        std::for_each(track.getNoteList().begin(), track.getNoteList().end(), print_track_name());
    }
};

struct print_note_name
{
    void operator()(const std::pair<long,Note>& note_pair)
    {
       cout << "---" << note_pair.second.getName() << endl;
    }
};

//In use...
std::for_each(playlist.getTracklist().begin(), playlist.getTracklist.end(), print_track());
```